# Python stack overlapped element cumulation

Tags: python, stack

I want to cumulatively add element on Arraystack in Python

```
class StockManager:

    __PROFIT = 0

    def __init__(self, o_name, o_surname):
        self.box = ArrayStack()
        self._name = o_name
        self._surname = o_surname

    def buy_shares(self, company, number, buy_price):
        StockManager.__PROFIT -= buy_price * number
        n = 0

        if len(self.box) < 2:
            """there is no overlapped elements when box has no element"""
            self.box.push(company) 
            self.box.push(number)
        else:
            while n < len(self.box):
               if self.box._data[n] == company:
               """every even index(n = 0, 2, 4, ...) refers to company name"""
               """every odd index(n = 1, 3, 5, ...), which is next to even index refers to number of buying"""
                    self.box._data[n + 1] += number
                    n += 2

               elif self.box._data[n] != company:
                    """ if there's no overlapping, then just put the elements """
                    self.box.push(company)
                    self.box.push(number)
                    n += 2
        return print(self.box._data)
```

and class Arraystack is like this:

```
class ArrayStack:
    """LIFO Stack implementation using a Python list as underlying storage."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Create an empty stack."""
        self._data = []                       # nonpublic list instance

    def __len__(self):
        """Return the number of elements in the stack."""
        return len(self._data)

    def is_empty(self):
        """Return True if the stack is empty."""
        return len(self._data) == 0

    def push(self, e):
        """Add element e to the top of the stack."""
        self._data.append(e)                  # new item stored at end of list

    def top(self):
        """Return (but do not remove) the element at the top of the stack.

        Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty.
        """
        if self.is_empty():
            raise AssertionError('Stack is empty')
        return self._data[-1]                 # the last item in the list

    def pop(self):
        """Remove and return the element from the top of the stack (i.e., LIFO).

        Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty.
        """
        if self.is_empty():
            raise AssertionError('Stack is empty')
        return self._data.pop()               # remove last item from list

    def print_contents(self):
        print("Stack content: {0}".format(self._data))
```

when I run stockmanager with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    P = StockManager("A","B")
    P.buy_shares("hyundai", 20, 100)
    P.buy_shares("hyundai", 20, 100)
    P.buy_shares("hyundai", 20, 100)
    P.buy_shares("lg", 20, 100)
```

the result is

```
['hyundai', 20]  => O.K
['hyundai', 40]  => O.K
['hyundai', 60]  => O.K
['hyundai', 60, 'lg', 40] => It should be ['hyundai', 60, 'lg', 20]
['hyundai', 60, 'lg', 60, 'lg', 40] => don't know why this result comes...
```

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your while-loop in `buy_shares`?

Comment: Also, why use a stack? Why not a dictionary?

Comment: Ah, since it is for practising data strucutre - stack- so I made and use stack rather than dictionary. I also think dictionary is far more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem lies in your `while` loop:

```
           while n < len(self.box):
           if self.box._data[n] == company:
               """every even index(n = 0, 2, 4, ...) refers to company name"""
               """every odd index(n = 1, 3, 5, ...), which is next to even index refers to number of buying"""
               self.box._data[n + 1] += number
               n += 2

           elif self.box._data[n] != company:
               """ if there's no overlapping, then just put the elements """
               self.box.push(company)
               self.box.push(number)
               n += 2
```

Imagine we've run:

```
P = StockManager("A","B")
P.buy_shares("hyundai", 20, 100)
P.buy_shares("hyundai", 20, 100)
P.buy_shares("hyundai", 20, 100)
```

And so far, everything has worked as planned. Now, you try:

```
P.buy_shares("lg", 20, 100)
```

So: `n == 0` and `len(self.box) == 2`, so we enter the loop.

The `if` condition fails, `self.box._data[n] != 'lg'`, so we go to the `elif` block:

```
           self.box.push(company)
           self.box.push(number)
           n += 2
```

Now, `box == ['hyundai', 60, 'lg', 20]` and `n == 2`. But wait! The loop condition is `n < len(box)`, but `len(box) == 4`, so we enter the while-loop again! This time, the `if` conditions passes this time since `self.box._data[2] == 'lg'`.

So you execute the body of the if-block:

```
           self.box._data[n + 1] += number
           n += 2
```

Now, `n == 4` and `box == ['hyundai', 60, 'lg', 40]`. This time, `4 < len(box)` fails and we exit the loop and your function ends.

Now, a stack seems like the wrong data structure to me. It's clunky to have to increase the size by two. If you *really* wanted to do this, I would suggest an approach like

```
offset = 0
i = -2
for i in range(0, len(self.box), 2):
    if self.box._data[n] == company:
        break
else:
    offset = 2
    self.box.push(company)
    self.box.push(0)
self.box._data[i + offset + 1] += number
```

But again, this is clunky. You would be better off using a `dict` for box, then the logic could be implemented simply as:

```
self.box[company] = self.box.get(company, 0) + 1
```

Or better yet, use a `defaultdict`

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> box = defaultdict(int)
>>> box
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {})
>>> box['lg'] += 20
>>> box
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'lg': 20})
>>> box['lg'] += 20
>>> box
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'lg': 40})
>>> box['lg']
40
```

Comment: I think 
 "for i (0, len(self.box), 2):"
made a grammatical error in python 3.5

Comment: @S.JHahn it was an error when I copied it over. It should read `for i in range(0, len(self.box), 2):`

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over an entire list using indices; if the first `company`/`number` doesn't match the stock you are buying, it is automatically appended to the end of the list; then the next set of indices will point to the *new* company that was just appended so it adds the number.  The `elif` is incorrect - you shouldn't append a new `company`/`number` pair till you have iterated through the whole list and didn't find it.

This is what you are doing

```
>>> a = ['a',1]
>>> n = 0
>>> comp, nbr = 'b', 2
>>> while n < len(a):
....    if a[n] == comp:
            print('comp found at', n) 
            a[n+1] += nbr
            n += 2
        else:
            print('n =', n, 'appending', comp) 
            a.append(comp)
            a.append(nbr)
            n += 2


n = 0 appending b
comp found at 2
>>>
```

This is what you could do to fix it:

```
>>> a = ['a',1]
>>> n = 0
>>> comp, nbr = 'b', 2
>>> while n < len(a):
        found = False
        if a[n] == comp:
            print('comp found at', n) 
            a[n+1] += nbr
            found = True
        n += 2


>>> if not found:
        a.append(comp)
        a.append(nbr)


>>> a
['a', 1, 'b', 2]
>>>
```

---

But as suggested in the comments, you would probably be better off storing your purchase in a dictionary.